# How can I insert a variable into a variable string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which I need to set a unique `title`:

```
var tmpImg = '<img src="/admin/icons/cross.png" title="' + title + '" />';

$(this).find("tr td input").each(function(){
    title = $(this).attr("value");
    $(this).hide().before(tmpImg);
});
```

What I want to happen, is that each time the `each` iterates over the `<input>`, it updates the `title` value in the `tmpImg` string. I know I could separate the img HTML like below, although I think this would get messy when I need to reuse the image later down the script.

```
var tmpImg = '<img src="/admin/icons/cross.png" title="';

$(this).find("tr td input").each(function(){
    title = $(this).attr("value");
    $(this).hide().before(tmpImg + title + '" />');
});
```

Comment: I find it mildly amusing that you spelled the word "variable" 2 different ways – both incorrect – [in the question title](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8969771/revisions#revbac494ba-2a4a-4d42-987e-d10db9de3e62) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These string replacement solutions are nuts. Just make a copy of the element and set the attribute on it directly.

```
var tmpImg = $( '<img src="/admin/icons/cross.png" />' );

$(this).find( "tr td input" ).each(function() {   
  $(this).hide().before( tmpImg.clone().attr( 'title', this.value ) );
});
```

Comment: this looks like what i would have put as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change the variable to sort of template:

```
var tmpImg = '<img src="/admin/icons/cross.png" title="$title" />';
```

Then replace it with the input value:

```
$(this).hide().before($(tmpImg.replace("$title", this.value)));
```

The above has minimal changes to original code, the better jQuery way though is this:

```
$(this).hide().before($("<img />").attr("src", "/admin/icons/cross.png").attr("title", this.value));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it, for what it's worth:

```
$(this).find("tr td input").each(function(){
    $('<img/>', {
        src: "/admin/icons/cross.png",
        title: this.value
    }).insertBefore(this).next().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put some kind of placeholder token in the string, then use `replace`:

```
var TITLE_TOKEN = '%%TITLE%%';
var tmpImg = '<img src="/admin/icons/cross.png" title="' + TITLE_TOKEN + '" />';

$(this).find("tr td input").each(function(){
    $(this).hide().before(tmpImg.replace(TITLE_TOKEN, $(this).attr("value")));
});
```

---

Side note: `$(this).attr('value')` is usually better written `this.value` or `$(this).val()`.